# how to make condition to check duplicate/same value in java

Tags: java, spring, service, model, conditional-statements

im new with java and flink. i still fail to make condition to check duplicate or same value from same field in 2 table. so i have 1 service file and 1 model file. i already use some code like next(),equal() but still not working. so i just learn to create service to insert data and i want to check if there is duplicate or same value in another table or inside table i use before insert data to table and delete it if there is duplicate value in table before insert and what best implementation for making this kind of service? better make it in model or service?. sorry bad english. thanks for help

im using java 8, flink and postgresql

i just expecting result using boolean. if there is duplicate is true and if not is false

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that a specific field in unique when inserting into a table you can modify your SQL schema by adding the UNIQUE constraint to that field. That will prevent any duplicates from being added. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/ddl-constraints.html

Now if you want to check against a table B to see if a particular record exists there before inserting into table A you might want to take another look at your SQL schema before you consider using a JAVA-based solution.

Can you give me an example of the kind of relationship between tables that is making you consider checking for duplicate fields?

Comment: okay for example a relation between table A and B is phone number. so before insert to table A i want to check if there is a same phone number or not in table B

Comment: and sorry i forgot to add it in question. i want to check duplicate value in table A and if true then delete data with same userid and add it after

Comment: I'm still wondering if this is not a symptom of an underlying issue with your schema. If tables A and B hold phone numbers but you want to make sure they never have duplicate ones ( and I understand that to mean that no same phone number should exist in both A AND B ) then I'd say the preferable solution would be to store phone numbers on a separate table that both A and B reference instead of checking for duplicates in your JAVA code before every data insertion. Have a look at: https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: yeah i just learning not finishing my job so i just curious how to do it in java

Comment: thanks for help by the way. so many people talk about flink and kafka and java so i just want to explore it